# Criar tabela com os dias do mês

Tags: php

Estou a criar uma tabela com os dias de cada mês desta forma:

```
<?php
function nome_mes($num){
$mes = '';
switch ($num) {
case 0:
continue;
case 1:
$mes = "JANEIRO";
break;
case 2:
$mes = "FEVEREIRO";
break;
case 3:
$mes = "MARÇO";
break;
case 4:
$mes = "ABRIL";
break;
case 5:
$mes = "MAIO";
break;
case 6:
$mes = "JUNHO";
break;
case 7:
$mes = "JULHO";
break;
case 8:
$mes = "AGOSTO";
break;
case 9:
$mes = "SETEMBRO";
break;
case 10:
$mes = "OUTUBRO";
break;
case 11:
$mes = "NOVEMBRO";
break;
case 12:
$mes = "DEZEMBRO";
break;
}
return $mes;
}

//salva em um array qtos dias tem no determinado mês
$array_num_dias = Array(); 
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ){
$array_num_dias[$i] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, 2018);
}

//cria TD colspan dos meses
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ){
echo '<td colspan="' . $array_num_dias[$i] . '">'.nome_mes($i).'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

//cria TD dos dias
echo '<tr>';
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ){
for($j = 1; $j <= $array_num_dias[$i];$j++){
echo '<td>' . $j . '</td>';
}  
}
echo '</tr>';
?>
```

O resultado é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pretendia poder selecionar o mês que pretendo visualizar e não todos ao mesmo tempo.
Gostaria também de perguntar se estou a fazer da melhor forma, para criar a tabela com os dias de cada mês

Comment: Basta utilizar um valor via *POST* ou *GET* e utilizar o `if` ao listar os meses. Ex: `if ($_GET['month'] == $i) { /* Exibe a tabela */ }`

Comment: @Valdeir Psr, pode colocar um exemplo de como aplicar esse `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basta eliminar os loops

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ){
```

> e criar uma variável `$i` com o valor igual ao mês pretendido:

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['mes'])){

$i=$_POST['mes'];

    function nome_mes($num){
    $mes = '';
    switch ($num) {
    case 0:
    continue;
    case 1:
    $mes = "JANEIRO";
    break;
    case 2:
    $mes = "FEVEREIRO";
    break;
    case 3:
    $mes = "MARÇO";
    break;
    case 4:
    $mes = "ABRIL";
    break;
    case 5:
    $mes = "MAIO";
    break;
    case 6:
    $mes = "JUNHO";
    break;
    case 7:
    $mes = "JULHO";
    break;
    case 8:
    $mes = "AGOSTO";
    break;
    case 9:
    $mes = "SETEMBRO";
    break;
    case 10:
    $mes = "OUTUBRO";
    break;
    case 11:
    $mes = "NOVEMBRO";
    break;
    case 12:
    $mes = "DEZEMBRO";
    break;
    }
    return $mes;
    }
    
    
    //salva em um array qtos dias tem no determinado mês
    $array_num_dias = Array(); 
    
    $array_num_dias[$i] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, 2018);
    
    
    //cria TD colspan dos meses
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    
    echo '<td colspan="' . $array_num_dias[$i] . '">'.nome_mes($i).'</td>';
    
    echo '</tr>';
    
    //cria TD dos dias
    echo '<tr>';
    
    for($j = 1; $j <= $array_num_dias[$i];$j++){
    echo '<td>' . $j . '</td>';
    }  
    
    echo '</tr></table>';

}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="number" name="mes" min="1" max="12" step="1">
    <input type="submit" name="Inserir" value="gerar">
</form>
```

---

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['mes'])){

    $i=$_POST['mes'];
    $a=$_POST['ano'];
    
    //Define a localidade de determinado país.
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    
    //Retorna um novo objeto DateTime formatado de acordo com um formato informado
    $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $i);
    $nome_mes = strftime( '%B', $dateObj -> getTimestamp() );
    
    
    //salva em um array qtos dias tem no determinado mês
    $array_num_dias = Array(); 
    
    $array_num_dias[$i] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $a);
    
    
    //cria TD colspan dos meses
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    
    echo '<td colspan="' . $array_num_dias[$i] . '">'.strtoupper($nome_mes).'/'.$a.'</td>';
    
    echo '</tr>';
    
    //cria TD dos dias
    echo '<tr>';
    
    for($j = 1; $j <= $array_num_dias[$i];$j++){
    echo '<td>' . $j . '</td>';
    }  
    
    echo '</tr></table>';


}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="">
Mês <input type="number" name="mes" min="1" max="12" step="1"><br>
Ano <input type="number" name="ano" min="1900" max="2099" step="1" value="2018" /><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

> São feitas validações do lado cliente mas seria conveniente fazer também do lado servidor.

[DateTime::createFromFormat](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: funciona, mas em vez de ser números a colocar no input, aparecerem os nomes do mês, é possível?

Comment: @Iniciante Melhor, nesse caso, eu acho, um select

Comment: eu estou a criar estas tabelas com os dias dos meses para depois gerar um horário por turnos, acha que estou a seguir o melhor caminho?

Comment: @Iniciante, ai só vendo o código completo

Comment: ainda só tenho isto criado em código, agora é criar uma tabela em mysql com os ciclos possíveis para os horários e depois queria ao inserir o nome do colaborador na tabela de cada mês preenchesse o horário logo para o mês completo. Ou o melhor processo não é este? É difícil arranjar uma forma de criar os horários por turno

Comment: @Iniciante, a melhor coisa a fazer é tentar criar algum código nesse sentido e se houver alguma dificuldade criar novo post com as dificuldades encontradas. Nesse post aqui tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta estão bem definidas e qualquer outra condição vai perder o foco.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84949/discussion-between-iniciante-and-leo-caracciolo).